how to get just the string of an element in a numpy array? removing the brackets and apostrophe
i am making a web scarping project and multiple links must be scrapped. The structure of the links is
www.xxxxxxx.com/{symbol}

i have a csv file with all the symbols so i imported pandas to import the dataset, used numpy to create an array of the symbols but printing them gives me in the form of
['{symbol}']

how do i remove the square brackets and the apostrophe??
i tried
symbol = pd.read_csv("path")
symbol = symbol['Symbols'].to_numpy()
count = symbol.size
symbols_list = symbol.tolist()
symbols_string = ', '.join(symbols_list)


for i in range(0,count):
    current_symbol = symbols_string[i]
    print(current_symbol)
    print(f"www.xxxxxx.com/{current_symbol}")

but the resulted link has a single letter like
www.xxxxxxx.com/A


Can you attach sample data, expected output in question for others to try the problem?

Why are you using numpy for this?

Please show sample content of your CSV file so as to remove any misunderstanding about what you're trying to achieve

If symbols_string is a single string, then symbols_string[i] will be ONE character from that string.  Did you try iterating on symbol_list or even symbol array?

I think you are doing too much for a simple task. Why are you using Numpy?
I assume you have the CSV something like this in your symbols.csv
Symbols
AAPL
GOOGL
MSFT
AMZN
TSLA

Using simple pandas should be enough for your use case,
import pandas as pd

# Reading the CSV
symbols_df = pd.read_csv('symbols.csv')

# Direct iteration over the column
for symbol in symbols_df['Symbols']:
    url = f"www.xxxxxxx.com/{symbol}"
    print(url)

Output:
www.xxxxxxx.com/AAPL
www.xxxxxxx.com/GOOGL
www.xxxxxxx.com/MSFT
www.xxxxxxx.com/AMZN
www.xxxxxxx.com/TSLA

Without the extra pandas,
import csv
with open("symbols.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # Skip the header row (assuming the first row is "Symbols")
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        symbol = row[0]
        url = f"www.xxxxxxx.com/{symbol}"
        print(url)


For such a trivial file structure I wouldn't use either of pandas or csv modules. Just read the file a line at a time (skipping the first line obviously)

@SIGHUP exactly

i used numpy cause thats what i was familar with, i was just trying to make it work somehow. Thanks for the help lemme try
